# Manual flushing doesn't delete all WAL files in YugabyteDB?

Tags: yugabytedb

I am trying to flush the WAL to SST files using [`yb-ts-cli --server_address=<> flush_all_tablets`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-ts-cli/#flush-all-tablets). After the flushing is complete, I still see exactly 3G of WAL in two tables. Any ideas knows why that might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Every yb-tserver has these default flags:

```
--log_min_seconds_to_retain=900
--log_min_segments_to_retain=2
```

So even if these logs are not needed because this tablet peer's memtables are flushed to SSTables, the database still retains some logs for situations, for example if another peer of this tablet falls behind by a little bit and needs to catch up.

The above two flags also guide log retention (in addition to what's not been flushed).